How to get rid of warning "lint TP1004 fs.existsSync(???*0*) is very dynamic" in nextjs 14.2.5 server
Using nextjs 14.2.5, in one of the server component, I need to save a temp file to server storage, the code works fine, but every time the server component is called, there's the this warning
lint TP1004 fs.existsSync(???0) is very dynamic
recorded in the log, how can I get rid of this warning?


Unfortunately, there is no way to fix that except to upgrade Next.js to v15.x or no use turbopack...
The more details:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/72782
https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/issues/5682

If you can't do that, you can try to add an empty string like '' to the input parameter. For me, that worked, and the lint tips were all gone.
// before
const stats = statSync(path);

// after
const stats = statSync(path || '');

